# How to use formatC so that numbers as a result of a simple arithmetic operation are correct?

Tags: r, format

The function `formatC()` produces wrong formats of numbers when a simple arithmetic operation is passed as `x`.

Example:

```
formatC(29, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0")
> "029"
```

This is correct. But when I do:

```
formatC(100*0.29, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0")
> "028"
```

What am I missing here? (R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `format = "d"`. The [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formatc.html) set out the various options for the `format` argument:

> equal to `"d"` (for integers), `"f"`, `"e"`, `"E"`, `"g"`, `"G"`, `"fg"` (for reals), or `"s"` (for strings). Default is `"d"` for integers, `"g"` for reals.

Neither `29` nor `0.29 * 100` are stored by R as an integer and they are not equal. You can see this here:

```r
class(29) # numeric
class(29L) # integer
sprintf("%.20f", 29)
# [1] "29.00000000000000000000"
sprintf("%.20f", 100 * 0.29)
# [1] "28.99999999999999644729"
```

Using integer formatting is truncating the second value to 28. Use an appropriate format for reals e.g.:

```r
formatC(100 * 0.29, width = 3, format = "g", flag = "0")
# [1] "029"
```

For more on why this occurs see: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)